# How to make a div using php into a hyperlink?

Tags: php, html, css

I have a link in the following div, it code is,

```
<a href="<?php echo of_get_option('block1_link'); ?>" class="blocklink"><?php _e('More', 'isis'); ?></a>
```

Now, I want to make the whole div a hyperlink. Please guide me. Thanks. The whole code is below,

```
<div class="midrow_blocks_wrap">
 <i class="fa <?php echo of_get_option('block1_logo'); ?> fa-3x icon"></i> 
<a href="#">
<div class="midrow_block">
<!--We need to make this div a link -->
<div class="mid_block_content">
<h3><?php echo of_get_option('block1_text'); ?></h3>
<p><?php echo of_get_option('block1_textarea'); ?></p>

</div>
 <?php if ( of_get_option('block1_link') ) { ?><a href="<?php echo of_get_option('block1_link'); ?>" class="blocklink"><?php _e('More', 'isis'); ?></a><?php } ?>
</div>


</div>
 <div class="shadow"><img  src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/service_shadow.png" alt="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" /></div>

</div>
```

Comment: i guess your downvotes are because you hardly mixing html and php. Also making a div to a link is easily done by wrapping the div into a `a`-tag

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the time when I'm trying to make a hyperlink fill a whole div I give the div a `position: relative` and the hyperlink a `position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; left: 0; top:0;` I developed this because wrapping a whole div in a hyperlink can be screwy.

It is usually much easier to do it that way. If you give a `z-index: 9` or some higher number you will cover most of your base for the div and then if you need other links or content in there you'll need to do a higher z-index.

Just a thought.